# Use elements of a list of strings in a string keeping the quotation marks

Tags: python, string, format

I have a list like this:

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'xyz']
```

and want to turn this into a string like

```
my_combined_list('foo', 'bar', 'xyz')
```

A straightforward way would be to do

```
s = "my_combined_list({})".format(l).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

which gives me the desired outcome. Is there a better way that avoids the two `replace`?

Comment: Just checking: you aren't planning on passing the final string to `eval`, are you? There are much easier ways to call a function with a variable number of arguments. In particular, `my_combined_list(*l)` would work.

Comment: Also, using `eval` is a "code smell".

Comment: @Kevin: No, I won't pass this to evil `eval` :) I create a script for another language from python which I can then just load there...

Comment: If you're using Python 3.6: `f'my_combined_list{tuple(l)}'`

Comment: @user3483203: Thanks, that also works!

Comment: @downvoter: why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"my_combined_list{t}".format(t=tuple(l))
```

Comment: That works and can even be simplified further to `"my_combined_list{}".format(tuple(l))`

Comment: If you want to add a Python 3.6 version: `f'my_combined_list{tuple(l)}'`